# Doker вопрос по работе с данными в контейнере

Tags: docker

Только начал изучать докер не могу для себя понять, допустим у меня приложение на vue, я поместил его в контейнер.

Далее я правильно понимаю, что созданный докер контейнер он только для деплоя, т.е. я не могу запустить приложение в контейнере и начать писать новый код чтобы он сразу обновлялся и также попадал в контейнер или как-то это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно смонтировать вашу рабочую директорию с кодом внутрь контейнера используя параметр `--mount` либо `-v` для `docker run`

Например так

```
docker run -t -i -v <host_dir>:<container_dir>  ubuntu /bin/bash
```

docker run --help:

```
-v, --volume list                Bind mount a volume
--mount mount                    Attach a filesystem mount to the container
```

Собственно документация:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount